# Scanning a String with a comma

Tags: java, string

I have created a `Scanner` with `system.in`.

How do I allow an input to be able to have commas in it without going to the next input?

For example:

```
System.out.print("Enter City, State.");
String location = scan.nextLine();
```

I cannot enter `city,state` because the language thinks I want to proceed to the next scanning input question. How do I allow commas in a scanning string?

*Whole Code

`Scanner scan1 = new Scanner (System.in);`

```
System.out.print ("City, State: ");
String location1 = scan.nextLine();

System.out.print ("Enter number: ");
number1 = scan.nextDouble();

System.out.print ("Enter number: ");
number2 = scan.nextDouble();

System.out.print ("City, State: ");
String name2 = scan1.nextLine();

System.out.print ("Enter #: ");
number3 = scan.nextDouble();

System.out.print ("Enter #: ");
number4 = scan.nextDouble();
```

Comment: Users browse mainly by tags. Please choose tags smart and carefully to attract the right folks :)

Answer (score 3):

`scan.nextLine();` will return the entire line, commas or not.

If that isn't what's happening, then the problem must be elsewhere and you should provide more code.

Re: full code: That still works. What is the error you're getting / unwanted behavior?

What I think is happening is that the `nextLine()` is catching the end-of-line character from your previous input.

What happens:

- Suppose you enter a number like `12.5` and press `enter`.
- The buffer that `Scanner` reads from now contains `12.5\n` where `\n` is the newline character.
- `Scanner.nextDouble` only reads in `12.5` and `\n` is left in the buffer.
- `Scanner.nextLine` reads the rest of the line, which is just `\n` and returns an empty string. That's why it skips to the next input: it already read "a line".

What I'd do to fix it:

```
System.out.print ("City, State: ");
String name2;
do{
    name2 = scan1.nextLine();
}while( name2.trim().isEmpty() );
```

What this loop does is it keeps reading the next line until there is a line with something other than whitespace in it.

Comment: i see my problem now. it deals with nextLine because the output is Enter City, State: // Enter number: // Enter number: // Enter City, State: Enter number: // where last line appears as so together when asking for input –

Comment: Can you print out name2 after you read it and post the output?

Comment: thats where the problem is. it appears as Enter City, State: Enter number: without letting me enter something for name2 (City, State).

Comment: thanks. that worked and I understand how why. Is there a way to totally avoid that step though? @trutheality

Comment: The easiest way to avoid it completely is to force every response to be on its own line and use `number = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());` for the numbers. That way each `nextLine()` gets rid of its own newline character.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution: get the next line as you're doing and then use String#split on it to split on the comma (either that or use a second Scanner object that takes that String as input).  If there is only one comma, then splitting on "," will give you an array that holds two Strings. You'll need to trim the second String to get rid of whitespace, either that or split on a more fancy regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use split as mentioned above, or you could create another scanner on the next line, this would especially be useful if you have more than one fields separated by a ",".

```
System.out.print ("City, State: ");
Scanner temp = new Scanner(scan.nextLine());
temp.useDelimiter(",");
while(temp.hasNext()){
      //use temp.next();
      //Do whatever you want with the comma separated values here
}
```

But I still suggest that if you are just looking at something as simple as "City,State" , go for split.

Comment: If he wanted that, he could just use the original scanner's `.next()`.

Comment: i see my problem now. it deals with nextLine because the output is

Enter City, State: //

Enter number:  //

Enter number:  //

Enter City, State: Enter number: //

where last line appears as so together when asking for input

Comment: @trutheality, thats right, but as I said, using the same scanner for larger test cases might not hold good. But as you have mentioned, for this case it is pretty trivial.